# Converting recursive function to node-cron job

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, node-cron

I'd like to convert a recursive function with setTimeout to a node-cron job, but am not sure how to return the parameters:

```js
async function Infinite(page, initData, updateData = new Map()) {
  // Check for updates
  // If found add to updateData
  // Delay function
  return Infinite(page, initData, updateData);
}
```

to

```js
 cron.schedule('*/15 8-18 * * *', (/*page, initData, updateData = new Map() ??*/) => {
  // Check for updates
  // If found add to updateData
  // return ???
 }
```

I imagine there will need to be IIFE placed in there somewhere, any help is welcome!

Comment: Return where? Where do you want those parameters to be returned and processed?

Comment: @MikaelsSlava returned as they are in the first function, to be used recursively.

Comment: you can move those parameters to upper scope as a variable. Everytime the cron job run, will check the values and also can update accordingly.